# How to create a zip of my Mercurial repo for release?

Tags: mercurial

As part of my release process, I want to create a zip file that is basically a dump of the hg working dir at the time of that particular release. What's the easiest way to do this in an automated way?

BTW, if I simply "zip -r  proj.zip" the zip will contain all sorts of things I don't want -- like compiled files, emacs auto-backups, and, yes, the .hg directory itself...

Comment: This is addressed in a Tips-and-Trick [entry](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Make_a_clean_copy_of_a_source_tree.2C_like_CVS_export) in Mercurial's website.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `hg archive`:

```
hg archive -t zip /destination/path/zipfile.zip
```

It also takes the standard `-r` option to archive a revision other than the tip.

Comment: Newer version will even guess the type directly from the file extension, so `hg archive foo.zip` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

How about `hg archive`?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @BradRem, of course it's an answer, it's the same as the accepted answer but less detailed.  I assume that I hadn't seen the other answer when I wrote this one.